# How to hook to action of another Orchard Module

Tags: model-view-controller, module, dependencies, orchardcms

**Given:** Module A and Module B up and running in Orchard CMS

**Objective:** Execute some code from Module B when action of Module A is invoked

**Details:** Module A updates the UserPartRecord table and Module B should update other tables when a new record is created

I see that i have to add some code (that calls the code of Module B) to the action of Module A, but how do i do that without hard coding of dependencies (using classes of Module B in Module A)?

Comment: Are you trying to post to a controller in module B? Or are you trying to just call code that's in B, from A? If the latter, how would that be possible without taking a dependency? Why would you call an action, rather than a service class?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Yep i simply want to execute some code when a user change occurs. I found a solution by digging in the Orchard source code, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking counsel with my pillow i did remember that a Orchard user is also a Orchard content item hence utilizing some content management interfaces should be the way to go.

Here's my solution:

**Module A** (updates Orchard users and should notify other modules)

```
public class UserController
{
  // public
    public UserController( ... ,
      Orchard.Security.IMembershipService aMembershipService,
      Orchard.ContentManagement.IContentManager aContentManager,
      System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.IContentHandler> aContentHandlers)
    {
      Logger = Orchard.Logging.NullLogger.Instance;

      mMembershipService = aMembershipService;
      mContentManager = aContentManager;
      mContentHandlers = aContentHandlers;
    }

    ...

    // this method updates Orchard users by utilizing the Orchard content manager / handler 
    // functionality to notify other modules about creation, update or removal of a user
    public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Update()
    {
      ...

      foreach (... lUser in lUserQuery)
      {
        // ... check whether a matching orchard user exists
        Orchard.Security.IUser lOrchardUser = mMembershipService.GetUser(lUser.IntranetLogin);
        if (lOrchardUser != null)
        {
          // update user
          ...

          // notify handlers about update (adopted from src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs)
          Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.UpdateContentContext lUpdateContext =
            new Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.UpdateContentContext(lOrchardUser.ContentItem);

          mContentHandlers.Invoke(aHandler => aHandler.Updated(lUpdateContext), Logger);            
        }
        else
        {
          // create user

          lOrchardUser = mMembershipService.CreateUser(...);

          // note: 
          //  no notify handling needed as mMembershipService.CreateUser() already notifies content handlers
        }
      }

      ...

      // remove deprecated users
      foreach (int lDeprecatedOrchardUserID in lDeprecatedOrchardUserIDs)
      {   
        // removeuser
        Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart lUserPart =
          mContentManager.Get<Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart>(lDeprecatedOrchardUserID);

        if (lUserPart != null)
        {
          // the following call removes the user (content item) and notifies content handlers about removal
          mContentManager.Remove(lUserPart.ContentItem);
        }
      }

      ...
    }

    public Orchard.Logging.ILogger Logger { get; set; }

  // private
    ...

    private Orchard.Security.IMembershipService mMembershipService;
    private Orchard.ContentManagement.IContentManager mContentManager;
    private System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<
      Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.IContentHandler> mContentHandlers;
}
```

**Module B** (gets notified when a Orchard user "change" occurs)

```
public class TestHandler : Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.ContentHandler
{
  // public
    public TestHandler()
    {
      OnCreated<Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart>(UserCreated);
      OnUpdated<Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart>(UserUpdated);
      OnRemoving<Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart>(UserRemoving);
    }

  // private
    private void UserCreated(Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.CreateContentContext aContext,
      Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart aUserPart)
    {
      // do Module B specific tasks when a user is created
    }

    private void UserUpdated(Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.UpdateContentContext aContext,
      Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart aUserPart)
    {
      // do Module B specific tasks when a user is updated
    }

    private void UserRemoving(Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.RemoveContentContext aContext,
      Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart aUserPart)
    {
      // do Module B specific tasks when a user is removed
    }
}
```